# Domain forwarding to new sub domain not working

Tags: htaccess, migration

I've a site `www.xyz.org` which I've migrated to `xyz.newsite.org`. It has been more than a month but Google is still showing `www.xyz.org` in the SERP. I've migrated another site exactly in the same way and at the same time and in 10 days Google picked it up.

It seems we can't indicate domain to sub domain migration in GWT. Here is the *.htaccess* I've placed in the `www.xyz.org`:

```
RewriteEngine On
# Redirect Entire Site to New Domain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} xyz.org$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://xyz.newsite.org/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I'm not sure if I'm missing anything else.

Comment: Have you tried to submit new subdomain in new GWT profile?

Comment: I've already create it in GWT and after

Comment: Probably, your new site is out of index because of content duplicate.

Comment: I've checked the new sitemap, it was pointing to the old urls. May be that's why and in the other site it was already ok.

Comment: Yes, it may be an issue.

Comment: So this question is closed?

Answer (score 1):

Based on @AgA's comment the problem was to do with the sitemap. To explain this for other users who may come looking...

As part of the sitemap standard the URL needs to be within the exact same domain. So when the sitemap was copied across to the new domain but was still pointing to the old domain's pages the pages on the new domain where not being indexed as they couldn't be found. When this happens the very first thing to do is to check your sitemap.xml file and if this is the issue correct the link URL's to make sure that they are compliant with the sitemap standard, after which you can reupload the sitemap in Google Webmaster Tools to have all your pages found.